# the volley response is the same regardless of parameters i pass

Tags: android, android-volley, token, wordpress-rest-api

I'm sending POST request to the wp-rest-api to get token in order to login a user from android app, i get the same response regardless the username and password that i pass here is my request code

```
private void login() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("username","isohunter1@hotmail.com");
            params.put("password","qweqweqwe123");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.  It only differs from mine by a couple of parameters.  Might be worth a try:

```
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
        {  
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                params.put("grant_type", "password");
                params.put("username","isohunter1@hotmail.com");
                params.put("password","qweqweqwe123");

                return params;  
        }

       @Override
       public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
           HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
           return headers;
       }
```

What response do you get in onResponse?

Comment: I'm getting the same response for every username and password, token then username(the test username), displayname (test display name), i mean when i change the username and password the response contains old username and password

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with the way you are calling the API, that is some factor of the way the API is handling the request, it's out of your hands.  In my code, I ignore any other return value except the token, which is used for other successive HTTP requests.